# Guess K permutations of alphabet at the Nth sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

I am totally confuse with this question. I understand that this question is a problem in permutations but I really don't know how to solve this.
Here is the questions:

A free raffle site intends to draw a string of letters of length 3. They open unlimited slots for guessing. The correct guess will get a prize of 10 billion. Mr. Dengklek asked his 17,576 dcuks to guess from AAA to ZZZ in lexicographical order (the 1st duck guessed AAA, the 2nd duck guessed AAB, the 17,576th duck guessed ZZZ) in order to win the prize. Then the 1532nd duck will guess the string...
A. CGX B. BFX C. BGX D. CGY E. AFX

I have tried to use the following formula to find the sum of permutations:
P(n, k) = n!/(n - k)!
it only get me to the number of the permutations not the 3 letter at the sequence of 1532nd. What is the possible solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first letter is $A$, then there can be $26 \times 26 = 676$ different combinations of letters for the remaining two positions.
This means that $A$ will be in the first position for ducks numbered from $1$ to $676$.
$B$ will be from $677$ to $1352$, and $C$ from $1353$ to $2028$.

So, we know that the duck we're looking for will have a string of the form $C\_\_$.
We still have $1532 - 1353 + 1 = 180$ strings left to go.
This time, the string $CA\_$ will appear $26$ times, just like $CB\_$, $CC\_$, $CD\_$, etc.

We have $180 = 6 \times 26 + 24$, which means we skip the first $6$ letters, putting us on the seventh letter, $G$.
Now, we have $CG\_$. We still need to move up by the remaining $24$ positions, which brings us to $X$.
Ultimately, the string at position $1532$ is $CGX$.

You can see this well if you write $1532$ as $26^2 \cdot 2+26^1 \cdot  6+ 26^0 \cdot24$.

Comment: oh my God, Thank you very muchhhh. This is very easy to understand. Sir, if you may, can you suggest me the best book to learn discrete math?